# Is this the right way to include a subdir in a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, subdirectory, lib

```
prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
bindir=@bindir@

CFLAGS  = -pipe -O2 -g `freetype-config --cflags` -c -Wall -Wno-multichar `cat @top_srcdir@/madlax.specs` 
CPPFLAGS= $(CFLAGS) -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor

CC      = @CC@
EXE = jpegtranslator
MLXLIBDIR = @top_srcdir@/src/kits/objs

SUBDIR = libjpeg
SRC := $(SUBDIR)/jcapimin.c jcapistd.c jccoefct.c jccolor.c jcdctmgr.c jcdiffct.c \
jchuff.c jcinit.c jclhuff.c jclossls.c jclossy.c jcmainct.c jcmarker.c jcmaster.c jcodec.c \
jcomapi.c jcparam.c jcphuff.c jcpred.c jcprepct.c jcsample.c jcscale.c jcshuff.c jctrans.c \
jdapimin.c jdapistd.c jdatadst.c jdatasrc.c jdcoefct.c jdcolor.c jddctmgr.c jddiffct.c jdhuff.c \
jdinput.c jdlhuff.c jdlossls.c jdlossy.c jdmainct.c jdmarker.c jdmaster.c jdmerge.c jdphuff.c \
jdpostct.c jdpred.c jdsample.c jdscale.c jdshuff.c jdtrans.c jerror.c jfdctflt.c jfdctfst.c \
jfdctint.c jidctflt.c jidctfst.c jidctint.c jidctred.c jmemmgr.c jmemnobs.c jquant1.c jquant2.c \
jutils.c

OBJS =  be_jdatadst.o be_jdatasrc.o be_jerror.o JPEGTranslator.o $(SRC)
OBJDIR := objs

include @top_srcdir@/makefile.rules

all :   $(OBJDIR) $(OBJDIR)/$(EXE)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR) -C $(SUBDIR)
```

The main part of concern is the $(OBJDIR) -C $(SUBDIR), because I don't really know if I also need the -I$(SUBDIR) or the -L$(SUBDIR), or if I just use -ljpeg

Comment: Note that you need to use the `$(SUBDIR)/` prefix for *all* source files in the subdirectory. And that using `$(SRC)` in the definition of `OBJS` is probably wrong. And you probably don't have a library at all to link with since you build all the sources of the library together with your final program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `-l` option (lower-case L) is for linking with a library, and `-L` is for adding a path to the linkers library-search-path-list.

And yes you need `-L` if you want to link with a library in a non-standard location using `-l`.

You *can* also skip both the `-L` and `-l` options, and provide the full path to the library instead.